# Overloading same method to print different data type arraylist

Tags: java, compiler-errors, overloading

My task is to overload the same method, to be able to use the same method name, to print to screen, the contents of the both array list contents.

Below is my code I have tried. But it's not working because both methods have same name?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tutotrial_2_1 {

public static void main(String[] args){
    //Creating integer type array list
    ArrayList<Integer>listOfAges = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //Adding items to array list
    listOfAges.add(25);
    listOfAges.add(36);
    listOfAges.add(45);
    listOfAges.add(67);
    listOfAges.add(87);
    listOfAges.add(32);
    listOfAges.add(33);
    listOfAges.add(45);
    
    //Creating double type array list
    ArrayList<Double>listOfMarks = new ArrayList<Double>();
    //Adding items to array list
    listOfMarks.add(25.4);
    listOfMarks.add(36.5);
    listOfMarks.add(4.45);
    listOfMarks.add(55.67);
    listOfMarks.add(55.7);
    listOfMarks.add(32.0);
    listOfMarks.add(33.0);
    listOfMarks.add(45.0);
    
    //Calling display function of integer array
    displayArray(listOfAges);
    displayArray(listOfMarks);
}

//Display fucntion of listOfAges array
public static void displayArray(ArrayList<Integer>list){
    for(Integer indexes : list){
        System.out.println(indexes);
    }
}
public static void displayArray(ArrayList<Double>list){
    for(Double indexes : list){
        System.out.println(indexes);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly is not working? Can you share your full error stacktrace? Also please make a space in `ArrayList<Double> list` and `ArrayList<Integer> list`

Comment: error: name clash: displayArray(ArrayList<Double>) and displayArray(ArrayList<Integer>) have the same erasure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [Java's type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) you can't overload a method over a generic type. In other words, you have two methods that resolve to `displayArray(ArrayList)`, so you'll get a compilation error for a doubly declared method.

Luckily, you don't really need an overloaded method here - since any object in Java has a `toString` method, you can just have one method that receives a list, iterates over it, and print each item:

```java
public static void displayArray(List<?> list){
    for (Object indexes : list) {
        System.out.println(indexes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem if you change your method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  //Creating integer type array list
  ArrayList<Integer> listOfAges = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  //Adding items to array list
  listOfAges.add(25);
  listOfAges.add(36);
  listOfAges.add(45);
  listOfAges.add(67);
  listOfAges.add(87);
  listOfAges.add(32);
  listOfAges.add(33);
  listOfAges.add(45);

  //Creating double type array list
  ArrayList<Double>listOfMarks = new ArrayList<Double>();
  //Adding items to array list
  listOfMarks.add(25.4);
  listOfMarks.add(36.5);
  listOfMarks.add(4.45);
  listOfMarks.add(55.67);
  listOfMarks.add(55.7);
  listOfMarks.add(32.0);
  listOfMarks.add(33.0);
  listOfMarks.add(45.0);

  //Calling display function of integer array
  displayArray(listOfAges);
  displayArray(listOfMarks);
}

//Display function of listOfAges array
public static <T> void displayArray(ArrayList<T>list){
  for(T indexes : list){
    System.out.println(indexes);
  }
}
```

It should work. The  is use as a generic type.